# Make a JavaFX application wait between an animation

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, javafx

I am working on a simple game using JavaFX. What I want here is that at the end of the loop, the application waits for a specified period of time, and then runs again.

When I run this code on the application thread, the view doesn't get updated and the Nodes disappear without me seeing the animation.

If I create a new thread, then nothing happens at all. Since this animation isn't run until the game has been completed, it doesn't matter if nothing else works until the animation is completed.

Below is my code and any help is appreciated.

```
private void playWonAnimation(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (Node block: tower02List) {
        double xTrans = rand.nextInt(800) + 700;
        double yTrans = rand.nextInt(800) + 700;

        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2500), block);
        xTrans = (xTrans > 1100) ? xTrans : -xTrans;
        translate.setByX(xTrans);
        translate.setByY(-yTrans);

        RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(1200), block);
        rotate.setByAngle(360);
        rotate.setCycleCount(Transition.INDEFINITE);

        ParallelTransition seq = new ParallelTransition(translate, rotate);
        seq.setCycleCount(1);
        seq.play();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all the animations into a `SequentialTransition`, separated by `PauseTransition`s:

```
private void playWonAnimation(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    SequentialTransition seq = new SequentialTransition();
    for (Node block: tower02List) {
        double xTrans = rand.nextInt(800) + 700;
        double yTrans = rand.nextInt(800) + 700;

        int translateTime = 2500 ;
        int oneRotationTime = 1200 ;

        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(translateTime), block);
        xTrans = (xTrans > 1100) ? xTrans : -xTrans;
        translate.setByX(xTrans);
        translate.setByY(-yTrans);

        RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(translateTime), block);
        rotate.setByAngle(360 * translateTime / oneRotationTime);

        seq.getChildren().add(new ParallelTransition(translate, rotate));
        seq.getChildren().add(new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1.0)));
    }

    seq.play();
}
```

Comment: When I do that, only the top block is affected by the animation. The loop executes and creates the animation for each individual block, but when the animation is played, the top block follows the animation while nothing happens to the others. It might be worth mentioning that the blocks in question are panes inside a VBox and the list is the ObservableList returned by VBox.getChildren().

Comment: Ah, yes: having the rotation's cycle count set to `INDEFINITE` means it never finishes, so the sequential transition never gets to run the second and subsequent animations. See updated solution.